# UITableView with Checkmark and Custom Accessory Button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkmark, uiaccessoryview

I am implementing a UITableView with a checkmark on the left of the label and a custom accessoryView with a button on the right side. The checkmarks are selected and deselected in didSelectRowAt(indexPath). The custom button 
for the accessoryView is implemented as follows:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow-right-light.png")?.maskWithColor(color: .white), for: .normal)
button.sizeToFit()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTest), for: .touchUpInside)
button.tag = indexPath.row
cell.accessoryView = button
```

However, there is a small area on the corner right of the table view (indicated in image below) that still responds to didSelectRowAt(indexPath).

[image: Area between button and tableView edge that still responds to didSelectRowAt(indexPath)]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can have the button snap to the rightMargin of the tablewView programmatically? I want the user to be able to hit the area from the button till the edge of the table without selecting the checkmark (indicated in image below):

[image: expected button selection area]

Thank you.

Comment: I might suggest creating a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass at this point. You’ve done a great job customizing the default cell style but the layout isn’t really modifiable. You can obtain the exact positioning desired with a custom cell, without making that button the accessory view.

Comment: Thanks @Joey, I was able to add edge insets to the button view and obtain the results I wanted :)